# Dirichlet distribution centered at a gaussian random field?

Tags: normal-distribution, python, dirichlet-distribution, random-field

I created three (100x100) synthetic images using values randomly drawn from a Dirichlet distribution as shown below. Each image represent the abundance values of some surface components (soil, water etc.) for a mixed pixel in remote sensing imagery.

The images are generated in order to test a spectral unmixing algorithm and since they are abundance images, the pixel values corresponding to each image sum to one. These images later will be used to generate synthetic image bands using spectral signature matrix of pure endmembers and the linear mixing model.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

abund=np.random.dirichlet((3,1,2), 10000).T

abundance = abund.reshape(3,100,100)
print(abund.shape)
rows = 1
cols = 3
fig = plt.figure()
for i in range(cols):
    fig.add_subplot(rows, cols, i+1)
    plt.imshow(abundance[i], cmap='gray')
plt.show()enter code here
```

Images generated :

[image: Abundance images drawn from Dirichlet distribution]

The problem is, even these images are adequate for given task, they do not represent a real world scene well. A better approach is to use gaussian random fields. But this time i don't know how to preserve the sum to one condition.

In a paper [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1712.01770.pdf) the author says;

> Data cube DC2 has 100×100 pixels
> and its abundance maps were sampled according to a Dirichlet
> distribution centered at a Gaussian random field, leading to
> piecewise smooth maps that also have steep transitions.

As seen in the paper, the author achieved to create synthetic images which are smooth.

My question is, how can i create a gaussian random field in python and center a Dirichlet distribution to a gaussian field?

Thanks in advance.